# Issue with accessing webpage (uploaded on wildfly)

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, wildfly, war

The creation of the docker container is made with this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 --name wildfly -d -it jboss/wildfly `/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`
```

When I'm creating the docker container I'm uploading a war file through the admin page which I can access on `port 9990`. As you can see from the log file, the upload of the war file 
ends successfully and the context path is `/TestProject`, but when I try to access the broswer (http://localhost:8080/TestProject/.../) the message I recieve is `"This page isn’t working"`.
The .war file is tested at locally installed wildfly and it's working.

Log file:

```
 12:24:01,974 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:24:02,135 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
12:24:02,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
12:24:02,580 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
12:24:03,175 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)
12:24:03,176 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
12:24:03,176 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
12:24:03,176 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
12:24:03,176 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
12:24:03,177 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
12:24:03,177 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
12:24:03,179 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)
12:24:03,180 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)
12:24:03,252 INFO  [com.musala.test.project.TestProjectApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Starting TestProjectApplication on 18aafab37ce1 with PID 53 (started by jboss in /opt/jboss)
12:24:03,253 INFO  [com.musala.test.project.TestProjectApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
12:24:03,296 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4750038e: startup date [Wed Nov 08 12:24:03 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
12:24:04,106 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
12:24:04,134 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
12:24:04,135 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 840 ms
12:24:04,581 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
12:24:04,585 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
12:24:04,588 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
12:24:04,588 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
12:24:04,589 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
12:24:04,589 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
12:24:04,766 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4750038e: startup date [Wed Nov 08 12:24:03 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
12:24:04,808 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped "{[/hello]}" onto public java.lang.String com.musala.test.project.TestController.test()
12:24:04,813 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
12:24:04,813 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
12:24:04,853 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
12:24:04,853 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
12:24:04,877 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
12:24:04,986 INFO  [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
12:24:04,997 INFO  [com.musala.test.project.TestProjectApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Started TestProjectApplication in 2.33 seconds (JVM running for 1132.907)
12:24:05,044 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP4  for context '/TestProject'
12:24:05,911 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/TestProject' for server 'default-server'
12:24:05,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 6) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TestProject.war" (runtime-name : "TestProject.war")
```

Created docker container (showing that the ports are open)
[image: Created docker container]
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do the logs say after you try to access the page? "This page isn’t working" doesn't look like standard message, does it come from the app or from the server?

Comment: It comes directly from the browser, it neither reaches the server nor the app

Comment: Are you sure the app uses 8080 inside the container? Try t connect to the container via ssh and check the app via `curl` from the inside of the container.

Comment: Hi, I've tried what you advised me. It returns that it is working correctly. Anything else that I may try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with running the container. Try adding access to the app from all interfaces:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 --name wildfly -d -it jboss/wildfly `/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`
```

The only thing that you were missing was: `-b 0.0.0.0`